# MudTable.Items is null even row has data

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I have a expenses MudTable table.

I want to display the total expense of the row data.

```
<MudTable Loading="@loading" Class="mt-15"
    ServerData="@(new Func<TableState, Task<TableData<InvoiceVm>>>(GetServerData))" @ref="_table">
    <HeaderContent >
        <MudTh>Invoice no</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Date</MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Invoice No">@context.InvoiceNo</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Date">@context.DateTime</MudTd>
       
    </RowTemplate>
        <FooterContent>
                  <MudTd colspan="6"><strong> Total expenses :</strong>  @_table.Items?.Sum((e) => (e.InvoiceDetails.Sum(x => (x.ProductPrice * x.Quantity))))</MudTd>
        </FooterContent>
</MudTable>
```

Here `@_table.Items?` is null that is why I could not print the total expenses.
But the table row has data.

Why `@_table.Items` is null?

```
    private async Task<TableData<InvoiceVm>> GetServerData(TableState state)
    {
       // removed rest
        return new TableData<InvoiceVm>() { Items = response.Data, TotalItems = response.MetaData.TotalCount };

    }
```

Comment: Hey, do you solve this? (also, I recently discover that it's not necessary to set the Loading element to see the loading feature, and de serverReload can be like ServerReload=GetServerData)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Apparently, the ServerData function does not populate _table.Items, so my solution was to assign it before returning TableData.

```
private async Task<TableData<InvoiceVm>> GetServerData(TableState state)
{
    // removed rest

    // Populate it here:
    _table.Items = response.Data;

    return new TableData<InvoiceVm>() { Items = response.Data, TotalItems = response.MetaData.TotalCount };
}
```